# listen loaded event of each resource (all scripts, css, images, etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, resources, loaded

I am working to a page loaded percentage bar based on every single resource in the page loading: I mean monitoring every image, or script, css, etc and  use its "loaded event" to increase the general page loaded percentage

I have readed in some posts that is difficult to monitor the loaded event of some elements, so my question is how to do it using javascript / jQuery?
What strategy can I use to achieve that result?

I tried something like this, but actually it is not working well

```
function calc(element){
    console.log(element.outerHTML);
    progress++;
    var loadingStatus = ( progress * 100 / totalLength );
    console.log(loadingStatus);
    document.getElementById('loadingBar').style.width = loadingStatus+'%';
}

document.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(document.readyState == "interactive"){

        progress = 0;
        var styleElements = document.querySelectorAll('style');
        var linkElements = document.querySelectorAll('link');
        var scriptElements = document.querySelectorAll('script[src]');
        var imgElements = document.querySelectorAll('img');
        totalLength = (styleElements.length + linkElements.length + scriptElements.length + imgElements.length);

        for(var i=0; i<styleElements.length; i++){
            styleElements[i].setAttribute('onload','calc(this);');
        }

        for(var i=0; i<linkElements.length; i++){
            var source = linkElements[i].href;
            linkElements[i].remove();
            var newLink = document.createElement('link');
            newLink.setAttribute('href', source);
            newLink.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
            newLink.setAttribute('onload','calc(this);');
            document.head.appendChild(newLink);
        }

        for(var i=0; i<scriptElements.length; i++){
            var source = scriptElements[i].src;
            scriptElements[i].remove();
            var newScript = document.createElement('script');
            newScript.setAttribute('src', source);
            newScript.setAttribute('onload','calc(this);');
            document.head.appendChild(newScript);
        }

        for(var i=0; i<imgElements.length; i++){
            imgElements[i].setAttribute('onload','calc(this);');
        }

    }
}
```

Actually some problems with this code are:

- Resources errors (fail load, 404, etc) break the percentage calculation
- `<style>` elements are ignored from the percentage calculation depending where they are placed (like after `<link>` elements, or before `<script>` elements)
- Resources loaded by css links actually are not recognized

---

**Update:** after some tests I started thinking that all this is completely useless, because removing and readding the elements (like scripts) I cause they are executed 2 times...

I was thinking to use document write to scan the source code, replace and do the stuff, but it is not only a bad idea, maybe it is not possible because I have to perform it at the end of the body (to get the full page source, head + full body), when all the script and stuff are already been executed...

So.. I do not know what to do, maybe there is no way to create that progress bar based on resources load, right?

Comment: The problem is, that usually at least stylesheets are linked in the `head` section, which is fully loaded and parsed before `body` starts to load. On the other hand, `body` is the only element you can put something to show on a page ...